# A Gaussian Mixture Model Is a Universal Approximator of Densities

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, gaussian-mixture-distribution, density-estimation

When discussing the concept of mixtures of distributions in my machine learning textbook, the authors state the following:

> A Gaussian mixture model is a universal approximator of densities, in the sense that any smooth density can be approximated with any specific nonzero amount of error by a Gaussian mixture model with enough components.

I only have a basic background in probability and statistics, and I have absolutely no idea what this section is saying.

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to explain this in a way that is more understandable to someone of my level.

Comment: I applied this idea once, very early in my career, to carry out quantum-mechanical calculations by using a basis of Gaussians to model bonds in organic molecules.  After weeks of running into problems I realized, to my chagrin, that the densities I was trying to approximate were so sharply peaked that it was hopeless to develop a good approximation without using a ridiculously large number of Gaussians, which are too smooth for the job.  Thus, one should always be cognizant of the distinction between a purely mathematical theorem and the practical needs of computation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The idea is that an arbitrary density on $\mathbb{R}$, $f(\cdot)$, can be approximated by a Gaussian mixture model 
$$g_k(\cdot;\boldsymbol{\omega,\mu,\sigma})=\sum_{i=1}^k \omega_i \varphi(\cdot;\mu_i,\sigma_i)$$
in the sense that
$$\mathfrak{D}(f(\cdot),g_k(\cdot;\boldsymbol{\omega,\mu,\sigma}))\stackrel{k\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$$
for some specific functional distance $\mathfrak{D}(\cdot,\cdot)$. This result only applies for weaker types of distance.

Comment: Thank you for the crisp answer. Could you elaborate on what you mean by weaker types of distance?

Comment: Are isotropic gaussian mixture models universal Approximators of densities?